# Made a change via phpMyAdmin to "wp_usermeta" table and it is wrong

Tags: wordpress

I have a website made in WordPress.

The web designer has gone out of business I think as I can't get in contact with him.

I have been trying to change the website theme design etc but had limited access to http://example.com/wp-admin. I had no access to the setting menus. I could add content to the website but I couldn't change the layout or the overall design in the dashboard, so I looked online for solutions and found this:

> To force your account into an administrator role, access your database via phpMyAdmin (most hosting providers offer this in their control panel), go to the wp_users table and find the row for your user_login . Note the ID of this row. Now, go to the wp_usermeta table and find the wp_capabilities row for your user_id . Set the value of this row to a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}"

I did this and logged out; when I tried to log back in to the WordPress administrator login page for my website it said this message:

> You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.

Is there a way to reverse this change I have made?

And is there a way to make myself the the administrator of my WordPress website?